# Tridion 2011: Firefox - Why if Login popup is escaped it shows xml error message?

Tags: firefox, tridion, tridion-2011

I was accessing the tridion URL on firefox 3.5 and above versions, it popups for userid and password.

Am using Tridion 2011 SP1 HR1.

At that time, by mistake I have escaped it. Page comes up with a XML error message rather than specific message

```
XML Parsing Error: no element found
Location: http://XXXXXXXXXXXX/WebUI/Editors/CME/Views/Dashboard/Dashboard.aspx#locationId=tcm:229-31229-2
Line Number 1, Column 1:
```

> **Is there any fix to show specific error message saying something like "User ID and Password needs to enter"**

### UPDATE:

To make you clear understanding,

*On IE 8 and Chrome 15*:

- If I escape/click cancel on the login popup window, it shows **White Screen**.

*On Firefox 3.5 and above:*

- If I escape/click cancel on the login popup window, it shows **NO ELEMENT FOUND**.

For your reference, see the screenshot of firefox.

### *Step 1:*

While login

[image: While login]

### *Step 2:*

After click of escape/cancel button on the login popup window.

[image: After login cancel/escaped]

Comment: This question is very unclear. What have you escaped?  What happens with other browsers? do you see any errors in the Tridion event viewers?

Comment: @ChrisSummers: I have escaped the login popup window. Am using windows user, for IE and Chrome i never get a login popup window.

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea what you mean by "I have escaped the login popup" please find another way to explain it in your question.

Comment: if by "I have escaped the login popup" you mean you just closed it without entering any data, then I can't reproduce your issue on Firefox 14, there I get a: 401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials. error as expected. Maybe it is due to a defect in Firefox 3.5?

Comment: @ChrisSummers: I updated the question with screenshots

Comment: @BartKoopman: I have pressed `ESC` button on the keyboard. Am not getting the access denied error. See my screenshot.

Comment: That sounds like a horrible Firefox issue to me, must be because its more than 3 years old and out of date ;o)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK - I think the first comment here is that I don't think you are using a supported/tested browser (FF 3.5 is over 3 years old). When I look at the config file for my system (Tridion 2011 SP1 HR1) I see the following supported browsers node:

```
  <supportedbrowsers>
    <browser name="Mozilla Firefox" regExp="Firefox/([6-9]|[1-9]\d+)" notTested="true"/>
    <browser name="Google Chrome" regExp="Chrome/(1[3-9]|[2-9]\d+)" notTested="true"/>
    <browser name="Microsoft Internet Explorer" regExp="MSIE (\d{2,*})" notTested="true"/>
    <browser name="Apple Safari" regExp="\(Macintosh;.+\).+Version/([6-9]|[1-9]\d+).+Safari" notTested="true"/>
    <browser name="Microsoft Internet Explorer 7" regExp="MSIE 7"/>
    <browser name="Microsoft Internet Explorer 8" regExp="MSIE 8"/>
    <browser name="Microsoft Internet Explorer 9" regExp="MSIE 9"/>
    <browser name="Mozilla Firefox 6" regExp="Firefox/6"/>
    <browser name="Mozilla Firefox 7" regExp="Firefox/7"/>
    <browser name="Google Chrome 14" regExp="Chrome/14"/>
    <browser name="Google Chrome 15" regExp="Chrome/15"/>
    <browser name="Apple Safari 5" regExp="\(Macintosh;.+\).+Version/5.+Safari"/>
  </supportedbrowsers>
```

This means that nothing under version 6 has been tested. So please double check with support, and see if the system still support your browser. I think you might need to upgrade your browser.

Secondly, you should always see some kind of error/access denied message when you refuse to enter a user name/password, so I am not sure why this is a problem that you see an error page. What are you hoping to see when you refuse to authenticate?

This is what I see when I use a supported version of FF:

[image]

If you are trying to prevent the username/password prompt, I suggest you look at your installation and make sure it is using integrated security, or save your password in the browser.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Once again, I will re-check at my installation and update you on the same.

Comment: Chris: Today when I open the tridion on FF 3.5 and above browsers, it shows proper error message says **"401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials."**.

Comment: That is great - Perhaps you can either accept this answer (if it helped), write one of your own (if you did something to fix it), or delete the question (as your problem seems to have gone away on it's own). That way we can help other people with similar issues